# What is the Cisco ASA DHCP Server Address Limit on higher end modles

Tags: cisco-asa, dhcp

I know on the Cisco ASA 5505 is limited to only a class C 254 addresses in the DCHPD pool, mainly because of physical resource limitations.

Does this hold true for higher end models likes the 5512-X or 5515-X?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [ASA Config Guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa91/configuration/general/basic_dhcp.html#wp1125251)

> For all ASA models, the maximum number of DHCP client addresses varies
>   depending on the license:
>
> •If the limit is 10 hosts, the maximum available DHCP pool is 32
>   addresses.
>
> •If the limit is 50 hosts, the maximum available DHCP pool is 128
>   addresses.
>
> •**If the number of hosts is unlimited, the maximum available DHCP pool
>   is 256 addresses.**

Example from an
ASA5512X:

```
# dhcpd address 10.206.0.1-10.206.254.254 inside
Warning, DHCP pool range is limited to 256 addresses, set address range as: 10.206.0.1-10.206.1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The DHCP server in the ASA does seem to be little more than a SOHO toy.

Among its various issues are:

- that 256-address pool limit applies to all models
- it can't be a relayed server, i.e., it can only serve pools corresponding to its own actual interfaces